# Is there any way to run asscroll package in react project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-2016, npm-package

I was searching a few libraries for scroll animations and I found a very good npm package called **@ashthornton/asscroll** and I wanted to use the same on my react project.

But I am not been able to implement the same. It's not working the way it should. Can someone help me implement the same package in react?

Here, are the links for [asscroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ashthornton/asscroll) package and a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/asscroll-react-9q9653?file=/src/App.js) for anyone to give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run it with react you need to initialize **ASScroll** inside useEffect and also make sure to point out which div element is **asscroll-container**.

Since this is a little different in react you need to add to the div *asscroll-container="true"* (keep in mind that true has to be passed as string).

I have added this library to my codesandbox as you can see [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/asscroll-react-forked-4b8fc6?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: But I think another main component is the wrapper that has the className=" page" because I tried removing that cause I am using mui as the styling library and by using only the asscroll-container="true", that is not working.
But, anyway, this helped a lot.

Comment: you may need to wrap it into extra div? would need to see an example

Comment: Yess!! I have wrapped it with an extra div. And that works!!

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from "react";
import ASScroll from "@ashthornton/asscroll";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const pageEl = document.querySelector(".page");

    this.asscroll = new ASScroll({
      // containerElement: '.my-container',
      scrollElements: pageEl,
      ease: 0.1,
      touchEase: 1,
      customScrollbar: true,
      scrollbarEl: ".my-scrollbar",
      scrollbarHandleEl: ".my-scrollbar-handle",
      scrollbarStyles: true,
      disableNativeScrollbar: true,
      touchScrollType: "scrollTop",
      disableRaf: true,
      disableResize: true,
      limitLerpRate: true,
      blockScrollClass: ".asscroll-block"
    });

    this.asscroll.enable();

    requestAnimationFrame(this.onRaf);
  }

  onRaf = () => {
    this.asscroll.update();
    requestAnimationFrame(this.onRaf);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div asscroll-container="true">
        <div class="page">
          <img
            src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ashthornton-gc/asscroll/master/docs/banner.jpg"
            alt=""
          />

          <div class="content">
            <h1 class="title">
              <span>A</span>
              <span>S</span>
              <span>S</span>
              <span>C</span>
              <span>R</span>
              <span>O</span>
              <span>L</span>
              <span>L</span>
              <span></span>
            </h1>
            <div>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam
                ornare quis nibh eget convallis. Nam aliquam tempus dolor, at
                blandit elit vulputate eu. Mauris iaculis sem at nulla euismod
                auctor. Duis dui risus, lacinia quis fringilla a, dictum a
                lectus. Aliquam id dui a nisi dignissim aliquet nec sed augue.
                Vestibulum congue felis sit amet iaculis scelerisque. Vivamus
                facilisis lacus sit amet eros eleifend dapibus in eget neque.
                Aliquam nisi urna, porttitor et nisi in, pretium lacinia orci.
                Cras vitae leo posuere, condimentum magna et, vulputate mi.
                Nullam maximus ullamcorper leo eu auctor. Quisque eget fermentum
                est, aliquet cursus libero. Sed scelerisque mauris sed enim
                tristique tempus ornare vestibulum quam. Etiam eget aliquam
                augue. In nec lectus convallis, lobortis risus in, euismod
                lorem. Sed eleifend nisi ut lorem convallis, nec blandit ante
                egestas.
              </p>

              <p>
                Quisque quis tincidunt nunc. In magna est, malesuada quis tempus
                id, fermentum eleifend urna. Fusce facilisis rhoncus nibh, eget
                pellentesque mauris rhoncus ut. Nulla congue vel lacus nec
                pellentesque. Praesent eget elit nisi. Ut eu enim arcu. Duis et
                nisi ligula. Maecenas eu ante eget augue pulvinar efficitur.
                Aenean vitae luctus dolor. Ut iaculis orci ut orci tincidunt, id
                efficitur nulla accumsan. Nullam feugiat porta hendrerit.
                Pellentesque eget fringilla leo. Quisque laoreet ligula quis
                consectetur aliquam.
              </p>

              <p>
                Nam vel auctor nisl. Cras vel suscipit nibh. Donec nec massa
                sagittis, vehicula magna ac, scelerisque velit. Etiam mollis
                felis orci, id placerat ipsum egestas a. Class aptent taciti
                sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos
                himenaeos. Aenean faucibus vulputate feugiat. Nam condimentum
                arcu urna, id tincidunt nisl rhoncus quis. Duis mauris mi,
                dapibus et nisl at, facilisis tristique lectus. Nam vel felis in
                metus hendrerit placerat ac quis massa. Nam eget turpis nunc.
                Nullam at tincidunt lacus. Nulla viverra magna in nisi semper,
                non interdum nunc tempus. In pellentesque porttitor bibendum.
                Vestibulum blandit congue tempor.
              </p>

              <p>
                Cras congue, nunc et imperdiet porttitor, dui nisl ultricies
                ipsum, sed bibendum neque leo auctor sem. Nam velit ipsum,
                dictum eget dolor pellentesque, pulvinar imperdiet purus.
                Quisque leo dui, eleifend non porttitor quis, auctor convallis
                tortor. Integer vel justo at odio suscipit gravida vitae ut
                tellus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                Mauris sapien urna, iaculis quis magna at, facilisis ultrices
                elit. Maecenas ac elementum metus, sit amet congue nunc.
                Maecenas vitae posuere lectus. Integer maximus neque at nunc
                vestibulum imperdiet. Aenean imperdiet ligula semper nibh
                dapibus facilisis. Pellentesque gravida dignissim lacus, et
                vulputate sapien dapibus commodo. Etiam efficitur facilisis
                sollicitudin. Quisque velit nulla, condimentum ac tellus eget,
                rutrum placerat ipsum. Cras auctor auctor sem sed ullamcorper.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/asscroll-react-forked-2ryuuv?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you!!
Just needed a hooks approach and I got one.
But really all help appreciated. Thank you very much!